# Get current logged in user id in MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've tried googling but all the results semms to be for older versions.

I'm trying to get the logged in user's id and then compare it to another table. 
In (sorta) clear text i mean like this:

```
 If (the current logged in user's id == Goals.UserId)
 {
     show all the logged in user's goal
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `Asp.Net Core` Identity, you could use their `extension` method to simplify access to it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
[…]

if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == Goals.UserId)
{
    // show all the logged in user's goal
}
```